# Majority Element Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, divide-and-conquer

I'm having trouble getting the right output on my "Majority Element" divide and conquer algorithm implementation in Python 3.

This should be relatively correct; however, it would still appear that I'm missing something or it is slightly off and I cannot figure out why that is.

I've tried some debugging statement and different things. It looks like on the particular case listed in the comment above the code, it's resolving -1 for "left_m" and 941795895 for "right_m" when it does the recursive calls. When it compares the element at each index to those variables, the counter will obviously never increment.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
# Input:
# 10
# 2 124554847 2 941795895 2 2 2 2 792755190 756617003
# Your output:
# 0
# 
# Correct output:
# 1

def get_majority_element(a, left, right):
 if left == right:
     return -1
 if left + 1 == right:
     return a[left]

 left_m = get_majority_element(a, left, (left + right - 1)//2)
 right_m = get_majority_element(a, (left + right - 1)//2 + 1, right)

 left_count = 0
 for i in range(0, right):
     if a[i] == left_m:
         left_count += 1
 if left_count > len(a)//2:
     return left_m

 right_count = 0
 for i in range(0, right):
     if a[i] == right_m:
         right_count += 1
 if right_count > len(a)//2:
     return right_m

 return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n, *a = list(map(int, input.split()))
    if get_majority_element(a, 0, n) != -1:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

Comment: Why would the correct output for the given sample input be `1` and not `2`?  `1` isn't even in the input!

Comment: I guess it's supposed to be binary, like if there is a majority element return 1 otherwise return 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When counting the appearance of left and right major elements, your loops go over the range(0, right). Instead, they should be going over the range(left, right). Starting from 0 may, and will cause returning incorrect major elements in the smaller subproblems.

Also, in addition to the problem of having incorrect starting indices in ranges your for loops cover, you seem to have a problem in your recursive call arguments, probably due to your intuition causing you to overlook some details. Throughout the get_majority_element function, you treat parameter *right* to be the first index that is not in the list, as opposed to *right* being the index of the rightmost element in the list.

However, in your first recursive call, you give the third argument as if it is the last element **included** in that list. If right is the index of the first element not in that list, it should actually be the same with the second parameter of the second recursive call you're making in the following line. So, **the third argument of the first recursive call you're making is less than it should be, by 1, causing you to overlook 1 element each time you recursively go down**.

Thirdly, you have an error in the if statements following the for loops, similar to the problem you had with loop ranges. You are dividing the occurances of the element for all len(a) elements, although you should only care about the subproblem you are currently working on. So, you should divide it by the number of elements in that subproblem, rather than len(a). (i.e. (right - left)//2)

You can find the working code below, and look [here](http://ideone.com/9Czm04) in order to observe it's execution.

```
def get_majority_element(a, left, right):
    if left == right:
        return -1
    if left + 1 == right:
        return a[left]

    left_m = get_majority_element(a, left, (left + right - 1)//2 + 1)
    right_m = get_majority_element(a, (left + right - 1)//2 + 1, right)
    left_count = 0
    for i in range(left, right):
        if a[i] == left_m:
            left_count += 1
    if left_count > (right-left)//2:
        return left_m

    right_count = 0
    for i in range(left, right):
        if a[i] == right_m:
            right_count += 1
    if right_count > (right-left)//2:
        return right_m

    return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n, *a = list(map(int, input.split()))
    print("n=" + str(n))
    if get_majority_element(a, 0, len(a)) != -1:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

Comment: I think you're absolutely right about the loops and I've corrected them; however, it would appear that in my initial example I was missing a crucial return statement that returns -1 when all other conditions aren't met. I've added this now. The example in its previous state would have always returned something other than -1. When I add this return statement in, the output is still incorrect so perhaps the placement of it can be adjusted?

Comment: @chrisl0lz I updated my answer to include your case.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I might have been getting confused as to what constitutes 1...N elements for sub problems. I made the assumption that len(a)//2  would be the appropriate N number of elements when the sliced arrays were applied to the function again; however, as you pointed out this was not the case and that I needed a more fitting length for the sub problem. Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use Boyers and Moore's algorithm to find the majority element among a list.  I am using a inbuilt function, count; so, if the majority element  is greater than half size of the list then it gives output of 1, otherwise 0.  You can find more in this link about Boyers and Moore's Algorithm on finding majority [Algorithm information here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html)

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def get_majority_element(a,n):
    maximum = a[0]
    amount = 1
    for i in (a[1:]):
        if not  maximum == i:
            if amount >= 1:
                amount = amount - 1
            else:
                maximum = i
                amount = 1
        else:
            amount = amount + 1
    output = a.count(maximum)
    if output > n//2:
        return 1
    return 0



if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n, *a = list(map(int, input.split()))
    print (get_majority_element(a,n))
```